# Can't find plasmawallpaperviewer

Tags: kubuntu, kde, software-installation

I recently get into this: [Plasma Wallpaper Tutorial](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/WallpaperHelloWorld#Running_the_Wallpaper)
My problem is:

```
plasmawallpaperviewer -p tutorial
```

When I try to do this, the konsole says:

```
The program 'plasmawallpaperviewer' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-bin
```

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-bin
```

And it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kde-workspace-bin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 201 not upgraded.
```

I have kde-workspace-bin, but not plasmawallpaperviewer, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Package: plasmate**

Do you have the package plasmate installed ?

With the Kubuntu 13.04 / KDE 4.10.5:

```
:~$ apt-file search plasmawallpaperviewer
kde-l10n-id: /usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/plasmawallpaperviewer.mo
plasmate: /usr/bin/plasmawallpaperviewer



:~$ apt-cache show plasmate
Package: plasmate
Priority: extra
Section: universe/kde
...
Description: IDE tailored for development of Plasma components
 A small IDE tailored for development of Plasma components,
 such as Widgets, Runners, Dataengines.
Homepage: http://projects.kde.org/plasmate
```

http://aseigo.blogspot.fi/2012/11/plasma-sdk-accreting.html

> plasma sdk accreting
>
> If you have used plasmoidviewer, plasamengineexplorer or
>   plasmawallpaperviewer from past releases of KDE Workspaces while
>   developing Plasma components, you may be surprised to find them gone
>   in the upcoming 4.10 release.
>
> Well, they aren't actually gone: they have been moved to the
>   plasmate...